# Is it okay to have extra static methods in a singleton class?

Tags: objective-c, singleton, static-methods, singleton-methods

I have written a singleton class (in objective-C) with methods:

```
//shared instance
+(void) sharedInstance;

//method to get all feeds.
-(NSArray*)getAllFeedItems;
```

So to use this I have to call `[[MyClass sharedInstance] getAllFeedItems];`

Now instead of that if I define a static method:

```
+(NSArray*)getFeedItems;
```

which in turn implements:

```
+(NSArray*)getFeedItems{
  return [[MyClass sharedInstance] getAllFeedItems];
}
```

So that now I can simply use: `[MyClass getFeedItems];`. Is there anything wrong in doing so? will it cause any issues or is it bad coding practice? 
For me it was just making the function Call easier.

Comment: This question is "primarily opinion-based". It really depends on your use, if you may authorize at some point not using the singleton, but creating a simple instance... If it's more readable to specify that by writing `[[MyClass sharedInstance] doSomething]`, it reminds that you are using a singleton...

Comment: @Larme Since the receiver is a class object, one is reminded.